# $\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\frac{k_1}{\alpha}{\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{\alpha}{k_1}}\sqrt{(j+k_2)\frac{k_1}{\alpha}\left[2-(j+k_2)\frac{k_1}{\alpha}\right]}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need to solve the following limit:

${\displaystyle \lim_{\alpha \to \infty}} \frac{k_1}{\alpha}{{\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\frac{\alpha}{k_1}} \sqrt{(j + k_2)\frac{k_1}{\alpha}\left[2-(j+k_2)\frac{k_1}{\alpha}\right]}}}$

Where $k_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $k_2 \in [0,1)$ are parameters.

If this cannot be solved, I think it's possible to simplify the evaluation by neglecting $k_2$ since $j$ goes to infinity. The limit to be solved would be:

${\displaystyle \lim_{\alpha \to \infty}} \frac{k_1}{\alpha}{{\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\frac{\alpha}{k_1}} \sqrt{j\frac{k_1}{\alpha}\left[2-j\frac{k_1}{\alpha}\right]}}}$

The only thing I know, if I did everything correctly, is that the expected result should be $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Is this even solvable?

EDIT:

Numerical evaluation of the relative term inside the limit for $\alpha=30$. The relative error is evaluated as $\frac{\left|\mathcal{S}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right|}{\mathcal{S}}$, where:

$\mathcal{S} = \frac{k_1}{\alpha}{{\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\frac{\alpha}{k_1}} \sqrt{(j + k_2)\frac{k_1}{\alpha}\left[2-(j+k_2)\frac{k_1}{\alpha}\right]}}}$

[image]

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: The upper limit of the sum reads $\alpha/k_1$. Unless $\alpha$ is a positive integer and $k_1 = 1$, I don't think the sum makes sense.

Comment: $\alpha$ is the variable of the limit, if it has to be an integer it is possible to substitute $\frac{\alpha}{k_1}$ with $\left[ \frac{\alpha}{k_1} \right]$. Rounding the quantity should provide the same result since $\alpha$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Moreover the numerical evaluation converges to $\frac{\pi}{4}$, but I'd like to have an anltycal solution

Comment: I've added some details of the numerical evaluation

Comment: Are the parentheses under the square root for integer part or they're just normal parentheses. Also, if you're willing to substitute $n = \frac{\alpha}{k_1}$ into the expression, I think I can show that it goes to $1$.

Comment: They are normal parentheses. I think the substitution is legit since $k_1$ is constant and $\alpha$ goes to infinity, but the result should be $\frac{\pi}{4}$.